# Dixon's diagram for BRS cohomology

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, cohomology, quantum-field-theory

The article by J. A. Dixon titled [*Calculation of BRS cohomology with spectral sequences*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104203468) (Comm. Math. Phys. Volume 139, Number 3 (1991), pages 495-526) describes in words a diagram that is not printed. Does anyone have a link to the diagram?

Comment: Isn't it the "diagram" in equation (124)?

Comment: Oh, that isn't the kind of diagram I'm used to for a spec seq thanks  - will try to do it in a more traditional grid